# How to open/edit/protect the local app.config file while debugging the application?

Tags: c#, configuration

All the below mentioned methods are used for the exe config file (the one inside the bin\debug folder).

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(execAssembly);

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(filepath);
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But I want to open the app.Config file in the application and make some changes to it **at debug time**. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with _debug time_? While you have your project open for editing code in Visual Studio or while you run your code inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I am running the code inside visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet to modify your `.config` file. Please note that you would need to give the proper permissions to your users to access the file:

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "app.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["yourkey"].Value = //your value
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: This still accesses the config file inside the bin\debug folder.

Comment: @Sayeesri It depends on the path that you specify.